# Cannot connect to PostgreSQL DB Via pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql

So, I installed a minimal install of Fedora 15 to create a server for a web application. I also installed PostgreSQL 9.1 from pgrpms.org. PostgreSQL install went well. Locally, I was able to initdb, start and psql in to change the postgres password.

Now, I have installed pgAdmin on a Windows system on the same subnet. However, I cannot connect.

I have edited `/var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data/postgresql.conf` to set `listen_addresses = '*'`. I have edited `/var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data/pg_hba.conf` to allow `host all all 192.168.1.0/24 trust`. I have also restarted after the changes (`service postgresql-9.1 restart`)

The error in pgAdmin is: could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060) Is the server running on host "192.168.1.110" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

The answer is yes. I didn't install a firewall, and disabled the one on my Windows-based workstation. I am able to ping and SSH into the server. tcpdump shows the connection attempt on port 5432 from pgAdmin does happen:

```
[root@cobalion yum.repos.d]# tcpdump port 5432
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
07:28:44.014920 IP totodile.mcs.local.54067 > 192.168.1.110.postgres: Flags [S], seq 3554805012, w in 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
07:28:47.023859 IP totodile.mcs.local.54067 > 192.168.1.110.postgres: Flags [S], seq 3554805012, w in 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
07:28:53.019464 IP totodile.mcs.local.54067 > 192.168.1.110.postgres: Flags [S], seq 3554805012, w in 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
```

I am at a loss to know where to look next? On the surface, seems like I should be able to connect. Any ideas? Can I somehow check from "inside" a running postgresql server what settings were loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tcpdump pretty much confirms that `iptables` is dropping the packets on the server side.  `tcpdump` inspects the packets before they're touched by the firewall.  If the firewall was not dropping the packets and postgres wasn't working, the kernel would RST the connection attempt:

```
07:39:14.878008 IP localhost.12343 > localhost.35259: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 1980582372, win 0, length 0
```

and you'd immediately get a connection refused rather than a timeout.

The only other thing I can think of is if you set an absurdly low connection limit on the server and it's already full.  I've never tried that to see what would happen, though I have a feeling it would reject connections rather than timing them out based on the behavior of various websites with db errors I run across all the time.  You could check postgresql's log to see if it mentions the connection attempt.

Comment: Dang it. I could have sworn I had checked that, but it was iptables. Oh well, thanks.